# Confused guy about Phonegap usage git or installation

Tags: cordova, phonegap-build, cordova-3

I am just a confused guy who is trying to create one android app using phonegap / cordova or both??(confused here as well)
Now I know the details of phonegap, but confused how to create my first app. I found very good tutorial which explains quite a bit in detail - 
http://www.adobe.com/devnet/html5/articles/getting-started-with-phonegap-in-eclipse-for-android.html

But i feel it is old somewhat. I thought of going the official websites. I followed this - 
http://phonegap.com/install/

but again not sure of first hello world app in Android or setup in eclipse in official docs.

I also read that I should not follow the official guide but download directly from Github and start from there. Phew...!!

Can any one please help me with latest version of phone gap and tutorial links if any..

FYI : I already created one app using cordova 2.2.6 js file but as it is starting of my ap..I want it correct first time before I get into wrong stuff too much in detail.

Please help (SOS) ..

Thanks..

Comment: try this one, http://blog.revivalx.com/2014/02/21/crud-operation-using-jquery-mobile-on-android-part-1/

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you just confused the words `phonegap` and `cordova`.

Cordova is nothing but the old version of phonegap. If you are using old version you have to start the command with cordova. To find your version just type in "`phonegap version`" I think `phonegap` again rolled back to `cordova`.

To install the latest use the below command line,

```
$npm install -g phonegap
```

to create your first app,

```
$phonegap create hello com.example.hello HelloWorld
```

to build,

```
$cd Hello
$phonegap local build android
```

Make sure you have installed SDK. To check you have installed SDK just type in `'android'` and verify you have the latest version of android installed.

I struggled a lot to run my first app using phonegap without config errors and now the count crossed hundred.

Answer (score 0):

Cordova is not the old version of phonegap. Cordova is the engine and Phonegap is like a distribution of that engine.

Basically they do the same thing but using a different way.

> Apache Cordova is a set of device APIs that allow a mobile app developer to access native device function such as the camera or accelerometer from JavaScript. Combined with a UI framework such as jQuery Mobile or Dojo Mobile or Sencha Touch, this allows a smartphone app to be developed with just HTML, CSS, and JavaScript.

Here is a good doc about how to install and using basic commands from console: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/guide_cli_index.md.html#The%20Command-Line%20Interface.